# Activity back stack button from push intent

Tags: android, android-intent

When I click to push notification(from my app), intent trigger and open message activity.
But back stack arrow close app in that way. How to add appropriate activity to back stack / what flag to use to return to previous activity (not to close the app), is there necessary to override OnNewIntent()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a parent to the activity you have deep linked to in the manifest, or you can add a back state when starting the activity.

Manifest:

```
<application ... >
...
<!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
    ...
</activity>
<!-- A child of the main activity -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Java:

```
// Intent for the activity to open when user selects the notification
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);

// Use TaskStackBuilder to build the back stack and get the PendingIntent
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                        // add all of DetailsActivity's parents to the stack,
                        // followed by DetailsActivity itself
                        .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                        .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html